# "error reading PNG header" runtime error

Tags: python, matplotlib, runtime-error

Every once in a while a plot I try to plot with `canvas.print_figure` of `matplotlib` is failing with a `RuntimeError` I cannot understand. It will be far to complex for me to provide a minimal running example (especially since I cannot really reproduce it), but I can put here the call and the traceback, and I hope someone will be able to point me to where I should look for in order to track down the issue.

Here's the function call:

```
canvas.print_figure(filename, papertype='a4', orientation='landscape',
                    dpi=300, format='png')
```

where `canvas` is a `FigureCanvas` instance and `filename` is something like `picture1110101.png`.

Here's the complete traceback (I've replaced long path names with dots):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../draw.py", line 235, in plot
    _plot(*args[1:], **kwargs)
  File ".../draw.py", line 177, in _plot
    dpi=dpi, format=ftype)
  File ".../matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2093, in print_figure
    **kwargs)
  File ".../matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 491, in print_png
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File ".../matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 439, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File ".../matplotlib/artist.py", line 54, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File ".../matplotlib/figure.py", line 999, in draw
    func(*args)
  File ".../matplotlib/artist.py", line 54, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File ".../matplotlib/axes.py", line 2086, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)
  File ".../matplotlib/artist.py", line 54, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File ".../matplotlib/axis.py", line 1053, in draw
    tick.draw(renderer)
  File ".../matplotlib/artist.py", line 54, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File ".../matplotlib/axis.py", line 240, in draw
    self.label1.draw(renderer)
  File ".../matplotlib/artist.py", line 54, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File ".../matplotlib/text.py", line 576, in draw
    self._fontproperties, angle)
  File ".../matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 226, in draw_tex
    Z = texmanager.get_grey(s, size, self.dpi)
  File ".../matplotlib/texmanager.py", line 510, in get_grey
    X = read_png(os.path.join(self.texcache, pngfile))
RuntimeError: _image_module::readpng: error reading PNG header
```

So it looks like something related to `TeX`. I do use `TeX`, and I have the following configuration line on the beginning of the package init file:

```
matplotlib.rc("text", usetex=True)
```

Any hints?

Comment: Can you try using the 1.4.0rc1 code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is caused when the png output from the latex -> dvi -> png conversion ends up as an empty but existing file.  The error is raised when mpl tries to read the png to add it to the canvas and fails because it is not a valid png (due to being empty).

As background, the way that mpl inserts latex into your figure with the Agg backends is by (iirc):

1. inserting your latex string into a template
2. making a system call to latex to render the template -> dvi
3. converts the dvi -> png with `dvipng`
4. reads the png back in and inserts it into your figure as an image

I would just catch the exception and try again.

Comment: Thanks! I understand, but why would matplotlib try to *read* the png? After outputting it, isn't it done already?